# How to trigger .load() function on click more then one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to refresh div every time when button is clicked... When I press button first time it works but not after first time...

Here is code:

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function(){
$("a").click(function(){
$("#refresh").load( "/home #content", function() {
});  
});
});
```

Comment: [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) `$(document).on('click', "a", function(){
        //Your code
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code . its [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) issue.

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function(){
    $(document).('click','a',function(){
      $("#refresh").load( "/home #content", function() {
    });  
   });
 });
```